# joomla's akeeba is backing up ALL tables on my db

Tags: database, joomla, backup

I have a database, my_db; and I have a joomla site, my_joomla_site, that stores its tables there. However, my_db also has other tables that are UNrelated to my_joomla_site.

When I use Akeeba Backup to backup my_joomla_site, Akeeba packs all of the tables from my_db. I only want it to pack/zip the appropriate tables of course.

Is there a way to tell Akeeba to only pack the appropriate tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akeeba Backup has a database tables exclusion functionality. Refer to their documentation here for answers:

https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/database-tables-exclusion.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that ... I'll check my version ... maybe I am using an old version of akeeba ... but the link you gave is directly on point. thanks.

Comment: No problem. Also, depending on your knowledge of PHP and Joomla! you can probably extend the functionality of Akeeba to only backup tables with a certain prefix (assuming your Joomla! tables all have a unique table prefix). No point reinventing the wheel though!

Answer (score 0):

Akeeba Backup Professional also has an option for Regular Expression filtering of database tables. Telling it to only backup the tables which use Joomla!'s db table name prefix is as simple as giving it a RegEx rule of !@^#__@ which means "do not back up anything whose name doesn't start with the currently configured db table name prefix". It's also in the documentation. If you don't want to spend money for supporting my software writing efforts, as Hanley wrote above, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. You can alwats write a .php regex filter file yourself. Just look into administrator/components/com_akeeba/akeeba/filters and administrator/components/com_akeeba/akeeba/abstract/filter.php for more information.